# execute aws command using php

Tags: php, powershell, amazon-ec2

I want to run a powershell script which contains a aws command, the command is for getting the ip address of currently running instances of aws. Via cmd I can get the currently running instances ip address by executing the executer.ps1 file.But ,through php the command is not get executed.In the executer.ps1 file I am calling python files also those are working fine.

this command is not working via UI,

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $id --query Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress
```

How to do this one ?

executer.ps1 file is,

```
Clear-Host
Clear-History
$Username = "**"
$Password = "***"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
$ips = @() 

Write-Host "----------------------------------"

Try
{
    echo "Creating Instances will start now..."
    python C:\AWS\Distributed-setup-3\CreateInstance.py
}
Catch
{
    echo "Instance not created"
    exit
}

Write-Host "----------------------------------"

echo "Creating setup...."
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60

python C:\AWS\Distributed-setup-3\statusCheck.py

Start-Sleep -Seconds 60

$content = Get-Content C:\AWS\Distributed-setup-3\InstanceId.txt
echo $content

Write-Host "----------------------------------"

ForEach ($id In $content){
    echo "execute.ps1 id"
    echo $id    
    $instances = aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $id --query Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress 
    $instance = $instances[1]
    $instance = $instance -replace '"' , ""
    $instance =  $instance.Trim()
    $ips = $ips+$instance
}

Write-Host "----------------------------------"

Clear-Content 'C:\AWS\Distributed-setup-3\ipconfig.txt'

ForEach ($i In $ips){
    #echo $i
    if($i -eq ($ips[0])){
        Write-Host "Master is "$i
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Client "$i
        $index = [array]::indexof($ips,$i)
        $index = $index+1
        if($ips[$index] -eq $null){
            $i | Add-Content 'C:\AWS\Distributed-setup-3\ipconfig.txt'
        }
        else{
            $i = $i+","
            $i | Add-Content 'C:\AWS\Distributed-setup-3\ipconfig.txt'
        }
    }
}

Write-Host "----------------------------------"

aws s3 cp C://AWS/Distributed-setup-3/ipconfig.txt s3://s3merahkee
aws s3 cp C://AWS/Distributed-setup-3/Input.yaml s3://s3merahkee


Write-Host "----------------------------------"

Write-Host "Executing jmeter distributed test on remote system" $ips

Write-Host "----------------------------------"

ForEach ($ip In $ips){ 
   if($ip -eq ($ips[0])){
        #echo "Executing hub"
        Write-Host "Master ip is "$ip
   }
   else
   {
        #Write-Host "Executing slave "$ip
        Start-Job "C:\AWS\Distributed-setup-3\instance_2.ps1" -ArgumentList $ip
   } 
}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 60

Write-Host "----------------------------------"

Get-job | Receive-Job

Write-Host "----------------------------------"

$hub = $ips[0]
echo -n "Executing Master :"$hub

Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hub -ScriptBlock { cmd.exe /c C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\gitclone.bat } -credential $Cred

Write-Host "----------------------------------"

ForEach ($ip In $ips){
    echo -n "Executing on remote system for reports " $ip
    Try
    {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ip -ScriptBlock { cmd.exe /c C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\report.bat } -credential $Cred    
    }
    Catch{
        echo "Unable to connect check the remote connection permission"
    }
}

Write-Host "----------------------------------"

ForEach ($id In $content){
    $instances = aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $id --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress' 
    $instance = $instances[1]
    $instance = $instance -replace '"' , ""
    $i =  $instance.Trim()
    #echo $i
    aws s3 cp  s3://s3merahkee/Logs/$i C:\AWS\Distributed-setup-3\Reports --recursive
    cd C:\AWS\Distributed-setup-3\Reports
    Rename-Item jmeter-server.log jmeter-server_$i.log
}

Write-Host "----------------------------------"

echo "Terminating instance"
ForEach ($id In $content){
   aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids $id
}

Write-Host "----------------------------------"
Write-Host "Execution completed"
```

In trail.php, I am calling the executer.ps1 powershell script

```
<?php
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 500);
        $output= shell_exec('powershell -command C:/AWS/Distributed-setup-3/executer.ps1');

        echo( '<pre>' );
        echo( $output );
        echo( '</pre>' );          
 ?>
```

Comment: try -File instead of -Command

Comment: @EBGreen, To call a file also I need to use a command. That I have tried, still I am phasing the same problem.

Comment: I don't have a PHP environment to play around with right now but I can give you some general ideas. You probably need to provide a path. This can get tricky depending on the system. On a 64 bit system you can generally use the %sysnative% environment variable. Alternatively you can just give the literal path if you don't care which bitness of powershell winds up running.